# Which server os to use for small office with very limited requirements

Tags: google-drive-api, windows-server, ubuntu-server, onedrive

We are currently moving to a new office. We currently use a combination of OneDrive and GoogleDrive to store all of our photography and shared folders however the new premises are not fibre ready so I do not want to use all the bandwidth on uploading / downloading photos. Therefore we require a really basic server.

I need the server to hold all images and shared files, then after 5pm open up OneDrive and GoogleDrive to begin the synch (whilst everyone is out of the office) then close those programs down before 7am the next morning.

Could anyone recommend a Server OS that would allow me to do this quite easily, it's the only requirement we have for the server.

I've heard that freeNas or Ubuntu may be a good way to go but have no experience with any.

I know this question isn't very specific to one language etc. however I'm not sure where else to ask it, so if anyone has any information on better places to post the question then I'd be really greatfull for that to.

Thank you
Glynn

Comment: Belongs on serverfault, or possibly superuser. Recommending hardware or software is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you I'll re-post this over there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most server OS'es should be able to fulfil your needs. If you want convenience, then I would suggest Ubuntu server. It's very easy to setup, compatible with most hardware and lots of documentation available on the interwebs. For your file sharing needs: I would suggest checking out Bittorrent Sync. It's really nice!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll look into Bittorrent Sync now.